# pytorch: Merge three datasets with predefined and custom datasets

Tags: pytorch, dataset, torch, torchvision

I am training an AI model to recognize handwritten hangul characters along with English characters and numbers. It means that I require three datasets custom korean character dataset and other datasets.

I have three datasets and now I am merging three datasets but when I print the `train_set` path it shows MJSynth only which is wrong.

```
긴장_1227682.jpg is in my custom korean dataset not in MJSynth
```

**Code**

```
custom_train_set = RecognitionDataset(
            parts[0].joinpath("images"),
            parts[0].joinpath("labels.json"),
            img_transforms=Compose(
                [
                    T.Resize((args.input_size, 4 * args.input_size), preserve_aspect_ratio=True),
                    # Augmentations
                    T.RandomApply(T.ColorInversion(), 0.1),
                    ColorJitter(brightness=0.3, contrast=0.3, saturation=0.3, hue=0.02),
                ]
            ),
        )
        if len(parts) > 1:
            for subfolder in parts[1:]:
                custom_train_set.merge_dataset(
                    RecognitionDataset(subfolder.joinpath("images"), subfolder.joinpath("labels.json"))
                )

        train_set = MJSynth(
            train=True,
            img_folder='/media/cvpr/CM_22/mjsynth/mnt/ramdisk/max/90kDICT32px',
            label_path='/media/cvpr/CM_22/mjsynth/mnt/ramdisk/max/90kDICT32px/imlist.txt',
            img_transforms=T.Resize((args.input_size, 4 * args.input_size), preserve_aspect_ratio=True),
        )

        _train_set = SynthText(
            train=True,
            recognition_task=True,
            download=True,  # NOTE: download can take really long depending on your bandwidth
            img_transforms=T.Resize((args.input_size, 4 * args.input_size), preserve_aspect_ratio=True),
        )
        train_set.data.extend([(np_img, target) for np_img, target in _train_set.data])
        train_set.data.extend([(np_img, target) for np_img, target in custom_train_set.data])
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/cvpr/CM_22/doctr/references/recognition/train_pytorch.py", line 485, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "/media/cvpr/CM_22/doctr/references/recognition/train_pytorch.py", line 396, in main
    fit_one_epoch(model, train_loader, batch_transforms, optimizer, scheduler, mb, amp=args.amp)
  File "/media/cvpr/CM_22/doctr/references/recognition/train_pytorch.py", line 118, in fit_one_epoch
    for images, targets in progress_bar(train_loader, parent=mb):
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/pytesseract/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastprogress/fastprogress.py", line 50, in __iter__
    raise e
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/pytesseract/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastprogress/fastprogress.py", line 41, in __iter__
    for i,o in enumerate(self.gen):
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/pytesseract/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 628, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/pytesseract/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1333, in _next_data
    return self._process_data(data)
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/pytesseract/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1359, in _process_data
    data.reraise()
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/pytesseract/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 543, in reraise
    raise exception
FileNotFoundError: Caught FileNotFoundError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/pytesseract/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 302, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/pytesseract/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 58, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/pytesseract/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 58, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/media/cvpr/CM_22/doctr/doctr/datasets/datasets/base.py", line 48, in __getitem__
    img, target = self._read_sample(index)
  File "/media/cvpr/CM_22/doctr/doctr/datasets/datasets/pytorch.py", line 37, in _read_sample
    else read_img_as_tensor(os.path.join(self.root, img_name), dtype=torch.float32)
  File "/media/cvpr/CM_22/doctr/doctr/io/image/pytorch.py", line 52, in read_img_as_tensor
    pil_img = Image.open(img_path, mode="r").convert("RGB")
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/pytesseract/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2912, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/cvpr/CM_22/mjsynth/mnt/ramdisk/max/90kDICT32px/긴장_1227682.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the arrangement of your three datasets because you are using docTR library, merging datasets in this library is different compared to normal `ConcatenateDataset` in PyTorch.

Print the size of the individual dataset so that you can check the actual length of a dataset and overall dataset size.

```
mjsynth_train = MJSynth(
            train=True,
            img_folder='/media/cvpr/CM_22/mjsynth/mnt/ramdisk/max/90kDICT32px',
            label_path='/media/cvpr/CM_22/mjsynth/mnt/ramdisk/max/90kDICT32px/imlist.txt',
            img_transforms=T.Resize((args.input_size, 4 * args.input_size), preserve_aspect_ratio=True),
        )

        print("MJSynth dataset size is", len(mjsynth_train))

        synth_train = SynthText(
            recognition_task=True,
            download=True,  # NOTE: download can take really long depending on your bandwidth
            img_transforms=T.Resize((args.input_size, 4 * args.input_size), preserve_aspect_ratio=True),
        )

        print("SynthText dataset size is", len(synth_train))

        train_set.data.extend([(np_img, target) for np_img, target in mjsynth_train.data])
        train_set.data.extend([(np_img, target) for np_img, target in synth_train.data])

        print("Overall dataset size is", len(train_set))
```